# Using GoJs in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gojs

im trying to create a parser tree in React Js for a NLP/POS-tagger project.i found that GoJs provides a cool parser tree [GoJs-parser-tree](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/parseTree.html),but i could not find documentation for react js implementation. i tried out some examples but i could not use it with react heres my code that i need to use it in react

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Parse Tree</title>
<meta name="description" content="A collapsible tree layout with all of the leaf nodes at the same layer." />
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2016 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="go.js"></script>
  <link href="../assets/css/goSamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  <!-- you don't need to use this -->
  <script src="goSamples.js"></script>  <!-- this is only for the GoJS Samples framework -->
  <script id="code">
    function init() {
      if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
      var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates
      myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          {
            allowCopy: false,
            allowDelete: false,
            allowMove: false,
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
            layout:
              $(FlatTreeLayout,  // custom Layout, defined below
                { angle: 90,
                  compaction: go.TreeLayout.CompactionNone }),
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true
          });

      myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
        $(go.Node, "Vertical",
          { selectionObjectName: "BODY" },
          $(go.Panel, "Auto", { name: "BODY" },
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              new go.Binding("fill"),
              new go.Binding("stroke")),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              { font: "bold 12pt Arial, sans-serif", margin: new go.Margin(4, 2, 2, 2) },
              new go.Binding("text"))
          ),
          $(go.Panel,  // this is underneath the "BODY"
            { height: 15 },  // always this height, even if the TreeExpanderButton is not visible
            $("TreeExpanderButton")
          )
        );

      myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,
          $(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 1.5 }));

      // set up the nodeDataArray, describing each part of the sentence
      var nodeDataArray = [
        { key: 1, text: "Sentence", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe" },
        { key: 2, text: "NP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 1 },
        { key: 3, text: "DT", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 2 },
        { key: 4, text: "A", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 3 },
        { key: 5, text: "JJ", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 2 },
        { key: 6, text: "rare", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 5 },
        { key: 7, text: "JJ", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 2 },
        { key: 8, text: "black", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 7 },
        { key: 9, text: "NN", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 2 },
        { key: 10, text: "squirrel", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 9 },
        { key: 11, text: "VP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 1 },
        { key: 12, text: "VBZ", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 11 },
        { key: 13, text: "has", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 12 },
        { key: 14, text: "VP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 11 },
        { key: 15, text: "VBN", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 14 },
        { key: 16, text: "become", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 15 },
        { key: 17, text: "NP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 14 },
        { key: 18, text: "NP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 17 },
        { key: 19, text: "DT", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 18 },
        { key: 20, text: "a", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 19 },
        { key: 21, text: "JJ", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 18 },
        { key: 22, text: "regular", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 21 },
        { key: 23, text: "NN", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 18 },
        { key: 24, text: "visitor", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 23 },
        { key: 25, text: "PP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 17 },
        { key: 26, text: "TO", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 25 },
        { key: 27, text: "to", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 26 },
        { key: 28, text: "NP", fill: "#f68c06", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 25 },
        { key: 29, text: "DT", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 28 },
        { key: 30, text: "a", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 29 },
        { key: 31, text: "JJ", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 28 },
        { key: 32, text: "suburban", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 31 },
        { key: 33, text: "NN", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 28 },
        { key: 34, text: "garden", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 33 },
        { key: 35, text: ".", fill: "#ccc", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 1 },
        { key: 36, text: ".", fill: "#f8f8f8", stroke: "#4d90fe", parent: 35 }
      ]

      // create the Model with data for the tree, and assign to the Diagram
      myDiagram.model =
        $(go.TreeModel,
          { nodeDataArray: nodeDataArray });
    }

    // Customize the TreeLayout to position all of the leaf nodes at the same vertical Y position.
    function FlatTreeLayout() {
      go.TreeLayout.call(this);  // call base constructor
    }
    go.Diagram.inherit(FlatTreeLayout, go.TreeLayout);

    // This assumes the TreeLayout.angle is 90 -- growing downward
    /** @override */
    FlatTreeLayout.prototype.commitLayout = function() {
      go.TreeLayout.prototype.commitLayout.call(this);  // call base method first
      // find maximum Y position of all Nodes
      var y = -Infinity;
      this.network.vertexes.each(function(v) {
          y = Math.max(y, v.node.position.y);
        });
      // move down all leaf nodes to that Y position, but keeping their X position
      this.network.vertexes.each(function(v) {
          var node = v.node;
          if (node.isTreeLeaf) {
            node.position = new go.Point(node.position.x, y);
          }
        });
    };
    // end FlatTreeLayout
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="sample">
  <h3>GoJS Parse Tree</h3>
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:500px"></div>
  <p>A <em>parse tree</em> is an ordered, rooted tree representing the structure of a sentence, broken down to parts-of-speech.</p>
  <p>
    This diagram uses a custom <a>TreeLayout</a> called <b>FlatTreeLayout</b> that places all leaf nodes at the same Y position.
    It also makes use of a <b>TreeExpanderButton</b> on the node template. See the <a href="../intro/buttons.html">Intro page on Buttons</a> for more GoJS button information.
  </p>
  <p>
    The abbreviations used in this diagram are:
    <ul>
      <li><b>NP</b>, a noun phrase</li>
      <li><b>VP</b>, a verb phrase</li>
      <li><b>PP</b>, a prepositional phrase</li>
      <li><b>DT</b>, a determiner</li>
      <li><b>JJ</b>, an adjective</li>
      <li><b>NN</b>, a common noun</li>
      <li><b>VBZ</b>, a third person singular present verb</li>
      <li><b>VBN</b>, a past participle verb</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this the code i got when trying to use it react

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import go from 'gojs';
const goObj = go.GraphObject.make;

export default class GoJs extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);

    this.renderCanvas = this.renderCanvas.bind (this);

    this.state = {myModel: null, myDiagram: null}
  }

  renderCanvas () {
    let model = goObj (go.TreeModel);
    let diagram = goObj (go.Diagram, this.refs.goJsDiv, {initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center});
    this.setState({myModel: model, myDiagram: diagram},
      () => {
        model.nodeDataArray = this.props.data;
        diagram.model = model;
        this.setState({myModel: model, myDiagram: diagram});
      }
    );
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.renderCanvas ();
  }

  componentWillUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
      console.log ('Updating');
      const model = this.state.myModel;
      const diagram = this.state.myDiagram;
      model.nodeDataArray = this.props.data;
      diagram.model = model;
      this.setState({myModel: model, myDiagram: diagram});
    }
  }

  render () {
    return <div ref="goJsDiv" style={{'width': '500px', 'height': '500px', 'backgroundColor': '#DAE4E4'}}></div>;
  }
}

GoJs.propTypes = { data: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired };
GoJs.defaultProps = { data: '[]' };
```

im unable to figure out whats missing and the out put i get from this is a total mess.

Comment: Note there is now the official example project: https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS-React-Basic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending hours of changing code here and there i managed to make what was required heres my final code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import go from 'gojs';
const goObj = go.GraphObject.make;

export default class GoJs extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);

    this.renderCanvas = this.renderCanvas.bind (this);

    this.state = {myModel: null, myDiagram: null}
  }

  renderCanvas () {

  function FlatTreeLayout () {
     go.TreeLayout.call(this);  // call base constructor
   }
   go.Diagram.inherit(FlatTreeLayout, go.TreeLayout);

   // This assumes the TreeLayout.angle is 90 -- growing downward
   /** @override */
   FlatTreeLayout.prototype.commitLayout = function () {
     go.TreeLayout.prototype.commitLayout.call(this);  // call base method first
     // find maximum Y position of all Nodes
     var y = -Infinity;
     this.network.vertexes.each(function(v) {
         y = Math.max(y, v.node.position.y);
       });
     // move down all leaf nodes to that Y position, but keeping their X position
     this.network.vertexes.each(function(v) {
         var node = v.node;
         if (node.isTreeLeaf) {
           node.position = new go.Point(node.position.x, y);
         }
       });
   };

    let model = goObj (go.TreeModel);
    let diagram = goObj (go.Diagram, this.refs.goJsDiv,          {
               allowCopy: false,
               allowDelete: false,
               allowMove: false,
               initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
               initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
               layout:
                 goObj(FlatTreeLayout,  // custom Layout, defined below
                   { angle: 90,
                     compaction: go.TreeLayout.CompactionNone }),
               "undoManager.isEnabled": true
             });

             diagram.nodeTemplate = goObj(go.Node, "Vertical",
                      { selectionObjectName: "BODY" },
                      goObj(go.Panel, "Auto", { name: "BODY" },
                        goObj(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
                          new go.Binding("fill"),
                          new go.Binding("stroke")),
                        goObj(go.TextBlock,
                          { font: "bold 12pt Arial, sans-serif", margin: new go.Margin(4, 2, 2, 2) },
                          new go.Binding("text"))
                      ),
                      goObj(go.Panel,  // this is underneath the "BODY"
                        { height: 15 },  // always this height, even if the TreeExpanderButton is not visible
                        goObj("TreeExpanderButton")
                      )
                    );

             diagram.linkTemplate = goObj(go.Link,goObj(go.Shape, { strokeWidth: 1.5 }));

    this.setState({myModel: model, myDiagram: diagram},
      () => {
        model.nodeDataArray = this.props.data;
        diagram.model = model;
        this.setState({myModel: model, myDiagram: diagram});
      }
    );

  }



  componentDidMount () {
    this.renderCanvas ();
  }

  componentWillUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
      console.log ('Updating');
      const model = this.state.myModel;
      const diagram = this.state.myDiagram;
      model.nodeDataArray = this.props.data;
      diagram.model = model;
      this.setState({myModel: model, myDiagram: diagram});
    }
  }

  render () {
    return <div ref="goJsDiv" style={{'width': '500px', 'height': '500px', 'backgroundColor': '#DAE4E4'}}></div>;
  }
}

GoJs.propTypes = { data: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired };
GoJs.defaultProps = { data: '[]' };
```

Since its a dumb(stateless) component we have to pass data from the parent component via props.

from  parent component

```
   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         <PTagBox data={nodeDataArray}/>
       </div>
     );
   }
```

where PTagBox is the dumb or child component

Comment: Did you ever end up using the DataInspector?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

import * as go from "gojs";
import { ReactDiagram, ReactPalette } from "gojs-react";

import "./styles.css"; // contains .diagram-component CSS`enter code here`
import solar_inverter from "./icons/Solar-Inverter.png";`enter code here`
import natgasIcon from "./icons/icons8-solar-panel-100.png";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

// ...

/**
 * Diagram initialization method, which is passed to the ReactDiagram component.
 * This method is responsible for making the diagram and initializing the model and any templates.
 * The model's data should not be set here, as the ReactDiagram component handles that via the other props.
 */

/**
 * This function handles any changes to the GoJS model.
 * It is here that you would make any updates to your React state, which is discussed below.
 */
function handleModelChange(changes) {
  alert("GoJS model changed!");
}

// render function...
export default function App() {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([
    // { key: 0, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue", loc: "0 0", src: natgasIcon }
  ]);
  console.log(nodes, "32");

  const [paletteNode, setPaletteNode] = useState([
    { key: "gasCompany", text: "Gas\nCompanies", icon: solar_inverter },
    { key: "oil", text: "Oil\nCompanies", icon: natgasIcon },
    { key: "gasProcessing", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Gas Processing" },
    { key: "gasFraction", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Gas Fractionation" },
    { key: "pyrolysis", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Pyrolysis (Cracking)" },
    { key: "basicP", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Basic Polymers" },
    { key: "intermediate", text: "Intermediates", icon: natgasIcon },
    { key: "lpg", icon: natgasIcon, text: "LPG, Naphtha,\nMTBE" }
  ]);

  const [linkData, setLinkData] = useState([]);

  function initDiagram() {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    var Colors = {
      red: "#be4b15",
      green: "#52ce60",
      blue: "#6ea5f8",
      lightred: "#fd8852",
      lightblue: "#afd4fe",
      lightgreen: "#b9e986",
      pink: "#faadc1",
      purple: "#d689ff",
      orange: "#f08c00"
    };

    var ColorNames = [];
    for (var n in Colors) ColorNames.push(n);

    // a conversion function for translating general color names to specific colors
    function colorFunc(colorname) {
      var c = Colors[colorname];
      if (c) return c;
      return "gray";
    }
    // set your license key here before creating the diagram: go.Diagram.licenseKey = "...";

    const myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, {
      initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform, // scale to show all of the contents
      ChangedSelection: onSelectionChanged, // view additional information
      "draggingTool.gridSnapCellSize": new go.Size(10, 1),
      "draggingTool.isGridSnapEnabled": true,
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
      // model: $(go.GraphLinksModel, {
      //   linkKeyProperty: "key" // IMPORTANT! must be defined for merges and data sync when using GraphLinksModel
      // }),
      model: $(go.GraphLinksModel, {
        linkKeyProperty: "key", // IMPORTANT! must be defined for merges and data sync when using GraphLinksModel
        // positive keys for nodes
        // makeUniqueKeyFunction: (m: go.Model, data: any) => {
        //   let k = data.key || 1;
        //   while (m.findNodeDataForKey(k)) k++;
        //   data.key = k;
        //   return k;
        // }
        // negative keys for links
        makeUniqueLinkKeyFunction: (m: go.GraphLinksModel, data: any) => {
          let k = data.key || -1;
          console.log(k, data, "94");
          setLinkData((prevLinkData) => [...prevLinkData, data]);
          while (m.findLinkDataForKey(k)) k--;
          data.key = k;
          return k;
        }
      }),
      ModelChanged: (e) => {
        // just for demonstration purposes,
        if (e.isTransactionFinished) {
          // show the model data in the page's TextArea
          // document.getElementById(
          //   "mySavedModel"
          // ).textContent = e.model.toJson();
        }
      }
    });

    // define a simple Node template
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate = $(
      go.Node,
      "Auto", // the Shape will go around the TextBlock
      new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(
        go.Point.stringify
      ),
      $(
        go.Shape,
        "RoundedRectangle",
        {
          name: "SHAPE",
          fill: "grey",
          strokeWidth: 0,
          portId: "",
          fromLinkable: true,
          toLinkable: true,
          cursor: "pointer"
        },
        // Shape.fill is bound to Node.data.color
        new go.Binding("fill", "color")
      ),
      $(
        go.Picture,
        { width: 64, height: 64 },
        new go.Binding("source", "icon")
      ),
      $(
        go.TextBlock,
        { margin: 8, editable: true }, // some room around the text
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay()
      )
    );

    // myDiagram.linkTemplate = $(
    //   go.Link,

    //   new go.Binding("relinkableFrom", "canRelink").ofModel(),
    //   new go.Binding("relinkableTo", "canRelink").ofModel(),
    //   $(go.Shape),
    //   $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "Standard" })
    // );
    myDiagram.linkTemplate = $(
      go.Link,
      {
        layerName: "Background",
        routing: go.Link.Orthogonal,
        corner: 15,
        reshapable: true,
        resegmentable: true,
        fromSpot: go.Spot.RightSide,
        toSpot: go.Spot.LeftSide
      },
      // make sure links come in from the proper direction and go out appropriately
      new go.Binding("fromSpot", "fromSpot", go.Spot.parse),
      new go.Binding("toSpot", "toSpot", go.Spot.parse),
      new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
      // mark each Shape to get the link geometry with isPanelMain: true
      $(
        go.Shape,
        { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 10 },
        // get the default stroke color from the fromNode
        new go.Binding("stroke", "fromNode", (n) =>
          go.Brush.lighten((n && Colors[n.data.color]) || "gray")
        ).ofObject(),
        // but use the link's data.color if it is set
        new go.Binding("stroke", "color", colorFunc)
      ),
      $(go.Shape, {
        isPanelMain: true,
        stroke: "white",
        strokeWidth: 3,
        name: "PIPE",
        strokeDashArray: [20, 40]
      })
    );

    // This function generates a unique key for a new link.
    // function getNextLinkKey() {
    //   setNodes((prevLinkData) => [...prevLinkData]);
    //   // Implement your logic to generate a unique key here, e.g., using a counter.
    //   // You can also use a library like uuid to generate unique keys.
    // }

    return myDiagram;

    function addLink(fromKey, toKey) {
      // Create a new link data object
      const newLink = {
        key: uuidv4(), // Generate a unique key for the link (using uuid or another method)
        from: fromKey,
        to: toKey
        // Add any other properties you want for the link
      };

      // Add the new link to the linkData state
      setLinkData((prevLinkData) => [...prevLinkData, newLink]);
    }

    function onSelectionChanged() {
      const selectedNodes = myDiagram.selection.first();
      if (!(selectedNodes instanceof go.Node)) return;
      let data = selectedNodes.data;

      //setNodes((prevLinkData) => [...prevLinkData, data]);
      setNodes((prevLinkData) => {
        // Check if any element in prevLinkData has the same key as data
        const hasDuplicateKey = prevLinkData.some((n) => n.key === data.key);

        // If there's no element with the same key, add data to the array
        if (!hasDuplicateKey) {
          return [...prevLinkData, data];
        }

        // If there is a duplicate key, return the original array without modification
        return prevLinkData;
      });

      console.log(data, "224");
      // if (selectedNodes.length === 2) {
      //   // Assuming you have a way to identify nodes uniquely (e.g., using their keys)
      //   const fromNodeKey = selectedNodes[0].data.key;
      //   const toNodeKey = selectedNodes[1].data.key;
      //   addLink(fromNodeKey, toNodeKey);
      //   addNode(data.text, "lightblue", data.loc, data.icon);
      // }
    }

    // function onSelectionChanged(data) {
    //   var node = myDiagram.selection.first();
    //   if (!(node instanceof go.Node)) return;
    //   var data = node.data;
    //   // console.log(data);
    //   var image = document.getElementById("Image");
    //   var title = document.getElementById("Title");
    //   var description = document.getElementById("Description");
    //   if (data.imgsrc) {
    //     image.src = data.imgsrc;
    //     image.alt = data.caption;
    //   } else {
    //     // let a = nodes.push(data);
    //     // return a;
    //     let b = (data) => {
    //       console.log(data, "106");
    //       setNodes(nodes.push(data));
    //     };
    //     b(data);
    //     // console.log(nodes);
    //     // console.log(data, "103");
    //     // setNodes((data) => {
    //     //   console.log(data, "106");
    //     // });
    //     // setNodes([a]);
    //     // setNodes([
    //     //   {
    //     //     key: data.key,
    //     //     text: data.text,
    //     //     color: "lightblue",
    //     //     loc: data.loc,
    //     //     src: data.icon
    //     //   }
    //     // ]);
    //     // data.icon = {};
    //     // image.alt = "";
    //   }
    //   // title.textContent = data.text;
    //   // description.textContent = data.description;
    // }
  }
  const paletteRef = useRef(null);

  function initPalette() {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    const myPalette = new go.Palette(paletteRef.current, {
      layout: $(go.GridLayout, { cellSize: new go.Size(1, 1) }),
      initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopLeft,
      initialScale: 0.8,

      nodeTemplate: $(
        go.Node,
        "Auto",
        $(
          go.Picture,
          {
            width: 50,
            height: 50,

            margin: 10
          },
          new go.Binding("source", "src")
        ),

        $(
          go.Shape,
          "RoundedRectangle",
          { name: "SHAPE", fill: "white", strokeWidth: 0 },
          // Shape.fill is bound to Node.data.color
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")
        ),
        $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 0 }, new go.Binding("text"))
      ),
      model: $(go.GraphLinksModel, {
        nodeDataArray: [
          { key: "gasCompany", text: "Gas\nCompanies", src: solar_inverter },
          { key: "oil", text: "Oil\nCompanies", src: natgasIcon },
          { key: "gasProcessing", src: natgasIcon, text: "Gas Processing" },
          { key: "gasFraction", src: natgasIcon, text: "Gas Fractionation" },
          { key: "pyrolysis", src: natgasIcon, text: "Pyrolysis (Cracking)" },
          { key: "basicP", src: natgasIcon, text: "Basic Polymers" },
          { key: "intermediate", text: "Intermediates", src: natgasIcon },
          { key: "lpg", src: natgasIcon, text: "LPG, Naphtha,\nMTBE" }
        ]
      })
    });
    myPalette.nodeTemplate = $(
      go.Node,
      // "Auto",
      "RoundedRectangle",
      {
        cursor: "pointer", // Set cursor to indicate draggable
        fromLinkable: true, // Allow outgoing links from this node
        toLinkable: true, // Allow incoming links to this node
        locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
        selectionAdornmentTemplate: $(
          go.Adornment,
          "Auto",
          $(go.Shape, {
            stroke: "dodgerblue",
            strokeWidth: 2,
            fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
          }),
          $(go.Placeholder)
        )
      },
      $(
        go.Picture,
        {
          width: 80,
          height: 70,
          margin: 5
        },
        new go.Binding("source", "icon")
      ),
      $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 0 }, new go.Binding("text"))
    );

    return myPalette;
  }

  return (
    <div className="gojs-wrapper-div">
      ...
      <ReactPalette
        id="palette"
        initPalette={initPalette}
        divClassName="palette-component"
        // nodeDataArray={[
        //   { key: "gasCompany", text: "Gas\nCompanies", icon: solar_inverter },
        //   { key: "oil", text: "Oil\nCompanies", icon: natgasIcon },
        //   { key: "gasProcessing", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Gas Processing" },
        //   { key: "gasFraction", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Gas Fractionation" },
        //   { key: "pyrolysis", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Pyrolysis (Cracking)" },
        //   { key: "basicP", icon: natgasIcon, text: "Basic Polymers" },
        //   { key: "intermediate", text: "Intermediates", icon: natgasIcon },
        //   { key: "lpg", icon: natgasIcon, text: "LPG, Naphtha,\nMTBE" }
        // ]}
        nodeDataArray={paletteNode}
      />
      <ReactDiagram
        initDiagram={initDiagram}
        divClassName="diagram-component"
        // nodeDataArray={[
        //   { key: 0, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue", loc: "0 0" },
        //   { key: 1, text: "Beta", color: "orange", loc: "150 0" },
        //   { key: 2, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen", loc: "0 150" },
        //   { key: 3, text: "Delta", color: "pink", loc: "150 150" }
        // ]}
        nodeDataArray={nodes}
        // linkDataArray={[]}
        linkDataArray={linkData}
        // onModelChange={handleModelChange}
      />
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).